# object of type 'int' has no len()

Tags: python

¿como hago para utilizar la fucion en esos Bucles anidados y poder evaluar los digitos de cada numero?
La finalidad del programa es que se ingresen una cantidad de numeros y el ultimo debe ser -1.
La salida es que imprima "numero ingresado es hyperpar" si todos sus digitos son pares.
De lo contrario que imprima No es hyperpar

```
def esPar(N):
    if N%2 ==0:
        return True
    return False  

lista_de_numeros=[]
while True:   
    numero= int(input())
    if numero == -1:
        break
    lista_de_numeros.append([int(a) for a in str(numero)])
print(lista_de_numeros)

for i in range(len(lista_de_numeros)-1):
   for j in range(len(int(i))):
     if esPar(j):
       print(i, "Es hyperpar")
     else:
       print(i, "No es hyperpar")
Salida del codigo
7666676
48602
42844
8965
-1
[[7, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6], [4, 8, 6, 0, 2], [4, 2, 8, 4, 4], [8, 9, 6, 5]]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-5c74d05115ae> in <module>()
     14 
     15 for i in range(len(lista_de_numeros)-1):
---> 16    for j in range(len(int(i))):
     17      if esPar(j):
     18        print(i, "Es hyperpar")

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Por lo que veo hay un problema de concepto con los ciclos `for`, así que te dejo un [artículo](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/bucle-for-en-python-ejemplo-de-for-i-en-range/) que lo explica sencillamente.

Puedes iterar por las listas que tienes utilizando el ciclo `for` de la siguiente manera:

```
for i in lista_de_numeros:
```

No hace falta poner ningún `range()` ya que el iterador `i` va a recorrer la lista completamente, lo mismo sería con el segundo `for` anidado

```
for j in i:
```

Línea `for j in range(len(int(i))):` está mal. `i` es una lista (Sería la sublista de la iteración actual de `lista_de_numeros`), por lo que `int(i)` produce un error, no puedes convertir una lista a entero, es posible convertir cada elemento de una lista (Por ejemplo con un ciclo for o con comprensión de listas) a entero pero no la lista completa de la forma en que lo hiciste. El error que aparecería es:

> int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'list'

En segundo lugar, los enteros (`int`) no tienen método `len()`, por lo que al intentar hacer `len(int())` te aparece el error que mencionas

Entonces, para poder recorrer toda la lista de listas, lo que puedes hacer es:

```
for i in lista_de_numeros:
    for j in i:
```

Ahora, para poder evaluar si un número es hyperpar o no, hay varias formas de hacerlo, podrías crear una función recursiva, o incluir un ciclo `for` adentro de la función en lugar del segundo `for` anidado o una forma sencilla sería crear una variable auxiliar para evaluar cada número y ver si es par o no

Por ejemplo:

```
for i in lista_de_numeros:
    es_par = True
    for j in i:
        es_par &= esPar(j)  # Operador lógico AND
    if es_par:
        print(i, "Es hyperpar")
    else:
        print(i, "No es hyperpar")
```

Lectura recomendada para entender la línea `es_par &= esPar(j)`: [Operadores básicos en Python](https://www.freecodecamp.org/espanol/news/operadores-basicos-en-python-con-ejemplos/)

Cabe mencionar que el ejemplo puede optimizarse, ya que por el momento evalúa cada número de las sublistas pero en realidad lo que podrías hacer es que si encuentra cualquier número que no sea par entonces continuar con la siguiente sublista (Eso te queda de tarea)

Es decir, si tenemos el número 1456, el código que puse como ejemplo evalúa 1, 4, 5 y 6, pero en realidad si cualquier número es impar podría saltar a la siguiente sublista, por lo que al encontrar que 1 no es par debería ignorar la evaluación de 4, 5 y 6 e imprimir que el número "No es hyperpar".

Comment: Habria alguna forma de que tomando el sigueinte ejemplo de entrada y salida: 20486
20
2000
4202486
-1
[[2, 0, 4, 8, 6], [2, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0], [4, 2, 0, 2, 4, 8, 6]]
[2, 0, 4, 8, 6] Es hyperpar
[2, 0] Es hyperpar
[2, 0, 0, 0] Es hyperpar
[4, 2, 0, 2, 4, 8, 6] Es hyperpar, se mostrara finalmente :
20486 es hyperpar
20 es hyperpar
2000 es hyperpar
4202486 es hyperpar

Comment: @victorManuelparraparra, como te puse en el comentario de tu pregunta anterior, es importante mantener una pregunta por publicación. Además, es importante que muestres un esfuerzo por resolver tus dudas ya que es un punto clave de la cultura de Stack Overflow. Te invito a que investigues un poco cómo hacerlo, si aún así no re sale, por favor crea una nueva pregunta e incluye el código que has intentado utilizar y con gusto te ayudamos. Saludos :)

Comment: @victorManuelparraparra, una pista, podrías buscar cómo convertir una lista a `string`, de esa forma puedes lograr lo que quieres hacer